# Selection Sort and Nested For Loop Python

Tags: python, selection-sort

I understand the concept of Selection Sort (I think) but what I'm confused about is trying to code it. From my understanding of Selection Sort, you set the first element as your minimum value and then compare it with the second element, and if the second element is smaller, you swap the elements together, making the second element your minimum value, and the previous min value goes to the position of where the second element was but if not, you continue looping through the list. You keep doing this until the list has been sorted.

```py
def selection_sort(arr):
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        minimum_index = 0
        for y in range(x+1, len(arr)):
            print(arr[minimum_index], arr[y])
            if arr[y] < arr[minimum_index]:
                minimum_index = y
        arr[x], arr[minimum_index] = arr[minimum_index], arr[x]
    return arr
```

I copied a code online, and changed it a bit to try and understand it. My question is, why can't `minimum_index` be equal to 0 if you're trying to compare it to other elements, and then swapping it. And also, why is `arr[x], arr[minimum_index] = arr[minimum_index], arr[x]` within the outer for loop body and not inside the inner for loop.

Is it also possible to try and explain in terms a beginner would understand and also maybe some example.

Sorry if any of the questions sound stupid. I'm still trying to understand Data Structures and Algorithms.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your first question: `minimum_index` is set to 0 right before the second loop. So, before updating it, you are indeed doing the comparison against `arr[0]`.

Comment: Second question: for a given `x`, chosen in the outer loop, once you got the index `y` that you want to swap, you do the swapping. The purpose of the inner loop is to get the index `y` for minimum `arr[y]`. If you were to make the swap before finishing the inner loop, you could do many swaps before getting the right `y`.

Comment: For a visual example, I would put the swap inside the inner loop, and add a printing statement right after that, so you can see what happens in each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: BTW, I tried it and didn't get my list sorted. I used `[35, 68, 16, 84, 2, 46]`. Did you tried the original code before changing it? Maybe it's because of your changes?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Sorry for the confusion on the first question. I'll try rewrite what I was trying to ask. I did `minimum_index = 0` because I thought we would be comparing the first element with the second and so forth, and if one of the elements is smaller than the first element, then `minimum_index` then becomes the index of the element that was smaller than the first element. I was just wondering why can't `minimum_index` be equal to 0 and why does it have to be equal to `x`. I hope this doesn't confuse anyone.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Yeah it initially didn't work for me, so I was trying to understand why it didn't work and I guess I was confusing myself even more lol

Comment: Yea, I was just going to say it works with `minimum_index = x`...

Comment: I think the problem you are having is your thinking about what *minimum* is. The minimum of concern changes as the algorithm progresses. The initial minimum is the actual smallest of all. Once that has been identified, the *minimum* of concern changes to the *next* smallest. This is also why only one swap is needed per round of the outer loop: Each round of the outer loop identifies a small value and the `x` values guards these against further swaps, ie it keeps a barrier between those that are sorted and those yet to be sorted.

Comment: @quamrana Ah I think I slightly get it. So from my understanding, before you said that, I guess my thinking of *minimum* is basically the first element and then comparing it to other elements, and then assigning `minimum_index` to the element that was smaller than the first element. Can explain a bit more as to why `minimum_index` has to be `x` in this case? I don't know why I'm still slightly confused. Thank you

Comment: One way of thinking about it is to think what happens on the second round of the outer loop. (The first time round, the minimum value was found and swapped into index `0`) Now, when you look at the comparisons, each element looked at: `arr[y]` is compared with `arr[minimum_index]` in which your code has set `minimum_index = 0`. This will now never be true since any element `arr[y]` cannot be smaller than the actual smallest value.

Comment: @quamrana I think I slightly get it. `Now, when you look at the comparisons, each element looked at: arr[y] is compared with arr[minimum_index] in which your code has set minimum_index = 0. This will now never be true since any element arr[y] cannot be smaller than the actual smallest value.` This part confused me though. So are you saying that `arr[0]`  will never change and that any element within `arr[y]` will never be smaller than `arr[0]` even though an element might be smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working code uses `minimum_index = x` instead of `minimum_index = 0`:

```
def selection_sort(arr):
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        minimum_index = x
        for y in range(x+1, len(arr)):
            print(arr[minimum_index], arr[y])
            if arr[y] < arr[minimum_index]:
                minimum_index = y
        arr[x], arr[minimum_index] = arr[minimum_index], arr[x]
    return arr
```

Let's start by answering your second question, and I think that would make the first one clearer:

For a given index `x`, chosen in the outer loop, once you got the index `y` that corresponds to the *minimum* element lesser than `arr[x]`, if there's one, you do the swap. The purpose of the inner loop is to get the index y for minimum `arr[y]`, not to swap once for every number lesser than `arr[x]`, but only for the minimum number lesser than `arr[x]`. If you were to make the swap before finishing the inner loop, you could do many swaps before getting the right `y`.
And that's why the swapping must occur in the outer loop, once the inner loop made it's job.

Now, once you have the minimum in the right position, you don't need to evaluate that position anymore, because now you know there's no other `arr[y]` lesser than this one.

Note that `minimum_index` was indeed equal to 0 in the first iteration of the outer loop.

To see it step by step, I modified it so it only prints the arrays at the beginning and in each iteration:

```
arr = [5,3,6,2]

def selection_sort(arr):
    print(arr)
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        minimum_index = x
        for y in range(x+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[y] < arr[minimum_index]:
                minimum_index = y
        arr[x], arr[minimum_index] = arr[minimum_index], arr[x]
        print(arr)
    # return arr   # commented so last line doesn't get printed twice

selection_sort(arr)

[5, 3, 6, 2]
[2, 3, 6, 5]
[2, 3, 6, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Ohhhh I think I understand the second question I asked. So from my understanding of it, you only want to swap once when two elements have been compared, hence why it's done within the outer loop. So for example, if we have a list of `[5,3,6,2]`, we would compare the first element with the others, and since `3` occurred first and is smaller than `5`, both would swap, instead of `5` swapping with `3`, and then `3` swapping with `2`, all in one inner loop?

Comment: Nope, in your example, is going to take 5, and compare it with every other through the second loop. Because 2 is the smallest, is going to swap 2 with 5, so you'll get `[2, 3, 6, 5]`. Now, because we know 2 is the smallest of all the smaller-than-five, there's no sense on comparing 2 with the rest anymore! See the version of my code with printed numbers. I edited it with your example :)

Comment: But how would it know 2 is the smallest, since there's an if statement that checks whether `arr[y]` is smaller than the current `arr[x]` and since 3 is smaller than 5, wouldn't it swap it round?

Comment: It checks whether `arr[y]` is amaller than `arr[minimum_index]` (which is `arr[x]` at first, but then get updated). Once a smaller is find, `minimum_index` changes to `y`, in the inner loop. So: first it finds that 3 < 5, but because it's still in the inner loop, it keeps comparing without swapping. Then, it finds 2 < 3, and changes `minimum_index` again. After the inner loop is completed, it makes the swap for the last `minimum_index` it found to be smaller.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I get it now. In my mind, I thought 3 and 5 would swap, and then 2 and 3 would swap, making it `[2,5,6,3]`, but then I realised that `minimum_index` is just storing the index of the element and not actually swapping it. This is starting to make so much more sense now. Thank you so much

Comment: Exactly, because... the swap happens in the outer loop!!  ; )